# How to use smart pointers in this case?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I have two classes: `Application` and `Graphics`:

HEADER FILE:

```
#include <memory>

class Application;

class Graphics
{
    private:
     
        const Application* _prApplication;//This is a reference pointer to a Application...

    public:

        Graphics(const Application* prApplication);
        ~Graphics(void);
}

class Application
{
    private:
        
        std::unique_ptr<Graphics> _graphics;

    public:

        Application(void);
        ~Application(void);
}
```

CPP FILE:

```
Application::Application(void)
{
    _graphics = std::make_unique<Graphics>(this);
}

Application::~Application(void)
{
    //NOTHING HERE...
}

Graphics::Graphics(const Application* prApplication)
{
    _prApplication = prApplication;
}

Graphics::~Graphics(void)
{
    _pApplication = null;
}
```

Shouldn't the `_prApplication` variable be a `weak_ptr`?

Let's say that, for some reason, the `Application` instance is deleted from the heap, wouldn't the `_prApplication` variable get dirty in the `Graphics` object that hasn't been deleted yet?

Is there a way to use a smart pointer in this case?

Comment: step back and find an answer to: Who owns the object?

Comment: a dynamically allocated object is not managed by a `weak_ptr` alone, because a `weak_ptr` is only an observer, it doesnt own the object

Comment: so, this is my question, the _prApplication 
should be an observer, no? std::weak_ptr<Application> _prApplication ?

Comment: Application is owner of the Graphics, and Graphics has a reference to Application

Comment: Why Graphics has a reference to Application?

Comment: the Application has variables that the Graphics class consumes, for example _window not shown in the statement to keep things simple.

Comment: Use `shared_ptr` (and its companion `weak_ptr`) when you *have to*.  Which is when there is no clear single owner of the object, and/or no clear lifecycle of the object; in which case federated ownership is an answer.  (It makes the object analogous to being a **global variable**.)  Otherwise, that's worth avoiding and instead use `unique_ptr` and non-owning raw pointers, with careful attention to object lifecycles and avoiding dangling non-owning raw pointers.  The example is a `unique_ptr` & non-owning raw pointer situation.

Comment: In your case Graphics will never outlive Application since it's unique_ptr managed by Application. Graphics upon construction not allocates new Application but uses existing this. In such case raw pointer will do, By the way you can construct Graphics on _window alone and not whole Application.

Answer (score 2):

There's no compelling reason why `_prApplication` must be a `weak_ptr`. It can be, but that's not going to accomplish anything notable, on its own. It just gets in the way. Either way you get a pointer to the object that owns the `Application`, except that a `weak_ptr` requires more finger practice to use.

It is more important to either delete or have a user-defined move constructor for `Application`. An instance of `Application`, as shown, can be moved, making the`_prApplication` pointer invalid.

Comment: I understood. I'm starting to use smart pointers now, and I didn't know what to do in certain cases. Thanks for the answer.